# No way of setting RSVP status for a user when authenticated as an application

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

**The documentation states:**

> rsvp_event: Enables your application to RSVP to events on the user's
>   behalf
>
> You can RSVP the user as 'attending' an Event by issuing an HTTP POST
>   to EVENT_ID/attending. This requires the rsvp_event permission and
>   returns true if the RSVP is successful, and false otherwise.

**The problem:**

If I am authenticated as an application then where do I pass the UID of the person whom I'm RSVPing on behalf of?

Comment: Can someone look into this please? We'd really like to get this working. Many thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly pass the user ID. Identity of the user is identified by the access token you pass.